# enumerating over a NSDictionary of a NSDictionary; extracting a certain key per NSDictionary element

Tags: xcode, json, parsing

I have a JSON response of:

```
{"result":
         [
            {"id":"1","inviter":"someguy1","invitee":"test","group_id":"1","status":"2"},
            {"id":"2","inviter":"someguy2","invitee":"test","group_id":"1","status":"2"}
         ]
}
```

I'm trying to print out all values for each dict by:

```
NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];

for(id object in res){
    NSDictionary *currentResult = (NSDictionary *)object;

    for(NSString *value in [currentResult allValues]){
        NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
    }
}
```

App is crashing with:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString allValues]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x96d43b0'

on the `for(NSString *value in [currentResult allValues])` line.

Any thoughts/advice/know-hows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is an `NSDictionary` with an `NSArray` that contains `NSDictionary`s.

Try this (not tested):

```
NSArray *dictArray = [json objectForKey:@"result"];

for(NSDictionary *dict in dictArray){
    NSLog(@"dict = %@", [dict description]);
}
```